SSH not doing MFA when logging in
I followed the steps here https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/configure-ssh-2fa#1-overview to set up SSH to do multi factor authentication using Google Authenticator app, on Ubuntu server 24.01.
However whenever I try to log in to SSH now (either using the console or SFTP/FileZilla) nothing happens for MFA, it doesn't ask me to enter anything, it just asks me for my password and when I enter it it says "Permission denied, please try again."
Lines I added to /etc/pam.d/sshd file
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_access.so accessfile=/etc/security/access-local.conf
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so

The first line lets me specify some IP addresses to by pass MFA.
Only line (non commented line anyway) added to /etc/ssh/sshd_config
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

In /var/log/auth.log
2024-05-29T16:09:11.021740+00:00 dbs-sftp sshd[1592]: pam_access(sshd:auth): access denied for user `paul' from `172.19.240.1'
2024-05-29T16:09:11.022333+00:00 dbs-sftp sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[1592]: Invalid verification code for paul
2024-05-29T16:09:12.935185+00:00 dbs-sftp sshd[1592]: Failed password for paul from 172.19.240.1 port 53501 ssh2

It says I used an invalid verification code but I didn't provide a verification code, it didn't ask me for one, I didn't get the chance to enter it.

Good that you linked the tutorial, but what you absolutely had to do is to put the configurations that you achieved while following it. We don't need tutorial (that much) to find out what's wrong with your system, but we need information about your system. Please, edit your question and add all the changed configuration files. Also, it's worth adding your authentication logs — there might be very useful hints as to what's wrong.

I have it working now, in the sshd_config file there was an entry for
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no

Apparently KbdInteractiveAuthentication means the same as ChallengeResponseAuthentication, so when I changed KbdInteractiveAuthentication to yes and deleted ChallengeResponseAuthentication all togeter it started working.

I also had issue with google auth MFA:
> ssh username1@10.0.0.2
username1@10.0.0.2's password:
Permission denied, please try again.

so I solved it just after below change in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no -> KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
with result:
> ssh username1@10.0.0.2
(username1@10.0.0.2) Password:
(username1@10.0.0.2) Verification code:

be aware that PasswordAuthentication yes - yes or no it doesn't matter
and in /etc/pam.d/sshd auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok - nullok param also can be absent

thanks Paul answer, I just extend his answer


This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

what do you mean? this is the answer and it solves the problem!
